# Integral in a complex number

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration

[image]
How i can calculate this integral in the picture?
That is :
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i\omega t - t^2 /\tau^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\sqrt{\pi}\,\tau\,e^{-\omega^{2}\tau^{2}/4}
$$

Comment: I cannot see any picture. Only 3 partial lines of a text photo.

Comment: 25 years ago I would have said "Use Gradshteyn and Ryzhik". Now I would say "Use Mathematica".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By completing the square, performing a $u$-substitution, and using the Gaussian integral formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you do the right substitution you get a Gamma function.

Or if you look at your handy integral tables

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ax^2 }dx = \sqrt{\pi / a}$$

Comment: The question is how to calculate the integral, not what the solution is. What is the right substitution. Moreover, I don't see how the formula you shown can help.

Comment: To fill the apparently not so obvious steps. Complete tona full square, do a substitution, you end up with a Gamma function. Or if you dont know how to calculate Gamma function simply look it up in your appropriate integrals table (ex. Bronstein) once all these teps are done, ask yourself why this is in the Physics stack instead of the Mathematics stack.